# Export formatting text in MS Word from Silverlight 4 application

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do I export formatting text in MS Word from Silverlight 4 application?

Comment: I don't understand your English grammar - can you rephrase?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export formatted text from a Silverlight 4 Application in DOCX format, you can try using Telerik's RadRichTextBox. There is a demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/MSWord) and you can test how it works.